# Difference between autoRemoveFromRecents and excludeFromRecents

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have gone through android docs but unable to get clear idea about these tags?  When should I use `autoRemoveFromRecents` and `excludeFromRecents`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

autoRemoveFromRecents: Whether or not tasks launched by activities with this attribute remains in the overview screen until the last activity in the task is completed.

excludeFromRecents: Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen.

In other words, autoRemoveFromRecents will allow the task to be in the overview screen, but will remove itself when the task is finished (i.e. all activities in stack finish()/onBackPressed()/etc.)

excludeFromRecents just never enters the overview screen in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.